# Как написать функцию по подсчету суммы элементов списка?

Tags: c++

Как написать функцию по подсчету суммы элементов списка?

Comment: @Bob1995, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Bob1995, перебрать все элементы списка и сложить их? Уверен, вам давали учебный материл по этому вопросу.

Comment: По-моему, такие вопросы губят ресурс.

Comment: Для типа list смотрите библиотеку alghrithm.

Comment: @perfect, думаете, это поможет?

@Bob1995, напишите сначала функцию, которая *строит список*. Потом Вы сами уже все поймете.

(конечно, можете ознакомиться с уже рассмотренными вопросами такого типа, набейте в гугле:

     site:hashcode.ru  сделать список c c++

и читайте (c и c++ -- латиница)).

Comment: поможет. плохо вопрос поставлен просто. но это не порок новичка. Чем чаще посещают подобные ресурсы, тем больше опыта приобретут.

Comment: @smallFish, я за то, чтоб перед регистрацией на вопроснике задавали несколько небольших тестовых вопросов для отметания неграмотных.

Comment: Не нужно отметать неграмотных. Просто при старте делать опросник и по результатам его выставлять три уровня "начинающий", "средний", "выше среднего". После набора 1000 очков можно попросить пересмотреть свой уровень. А в своих настройках можно отметить "затенять вопросы от людей, уровень которых такой-то".

Comment: @perfect, а мне кажется (судя именно по тому, как составлен вопрос), что пока изучение C++ библиотеки alghrithm автору никак не поможет.

Просто текущий уровень знаний не позволит понять, как ее использовать.

--

@KoVadim, идея хорошая. Правда, в необходимости наличия уровня (количества очков) для "пересдачи экзамена" я сомневаюсь. 

Но, дело-то не в этом, а в возможности практической реализации этой идеи.

Answer (score 4):

Если это production-код, используйте [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Если это учебное задание, спросите у девочек, сидящих за первой партой, они помогут.

Comment: Это лучший ответ! Голосуем за его принятие!

Comment: Даже если не помогут. Это повод их спросить!

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь командой `for` для перебора элементов и оператором `+` для суммирования.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший пример

```
int array[size];  //тут может быть vector, list ...

int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    sum += array[i];
```

ptintf("Сумма елементов array = %d", sum);